# Solving UnknownBackend error in google colab

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run a Python program in Google Colab. But I am getting this error.

> UnknownBackend: No event loop integration for 'inline'. Supported event loops are: qt, qt4, qt5, gtk, gtk2, gtk3, tk, wx, pyglet, glut, osx

> [TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | GUI event loop or pylab initialization failed

Can someone please help me in solving this error?

Comment: Hey, do you find the solution?